# could not find function tagPOS

Tags: r, opennlp

Trying to tag a sentence using openNLP.

```
library(openNLP)
str <- "this is a the first sentence."
tagged_str <-  tagPOS(str)
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "tagPOS"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need this function:`Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(language = "en", probs = FALSE, model = NULL)`. I took this from the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/openNLP.pdf):

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think `tagPOS` is not a built in function of any of the package, so you'll have to add the function.

***Here is the R Code:***

```
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)

tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
  s <- as.String(x)
  word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
  a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
  a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
  a3 <- annotate(s, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
  a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
  POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
  POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
  list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}

str <- "this is a the first sentence."
tagged_str <-  tagPOS(str)
```

***Output:***

```
> tagged_str
$POStagged
[1] "this/DT is/VBZ a/DT the/DT first/JJ sentence/NN ./."

$POStags
[1] "DT"  "VBZ" "DT"  "DT"  "JJ"  "NN"  "."
```

Hope this helps.