# Extract Pronouns from text in R

Tags: r, tm

```
sample_text <- ' Ramesh is my frien. He is a very good man'
```

Now I need to extract all the Pronouns (`PRP` or `PRP$`) from my text

```
acqTag <- tagPOS(sample_text)
```

I get the following

```
$POStagged 
 [1] "Ramesh/NNP is/VBZ my/PRP$ frien/NN ./. He/PRP is/VBZ a/DT very/RB good/JJ man/NN"
$POStags
 [1] "NNP"  "VBZ"  "PRP$" "NN"   "."    "PRP"  "VBZ"  "DT"   "RB"   "JJ"   "NN"
```

Now How do I get ony pronouns from here ? `PRP or PRP$`

Comment: something like `stringr::str_extract_all(acqTag$POStagged,"[[:alpha:]]/PRP")`.  What package is `tagPOS` from ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker I was thinking the same thing. I think this is it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764056/could-not-find-function-tagpos

Comment: @BenBolker Sorry the above syntax you had mentioned does not give me the desired output. Seems it needs to be checked again! Thanks!

Comment: note I said "something like".  I posted as a comment because I thought it might be useful, but didn't have time to test ...

Comment: Sure! I was just mentioning that it is not working. In any case thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What, exactly, do you want as the output? This seems to give what I think you want:

```
library("stringr")

prp <- str_extract_all(acqTag$POStagged,"\\w+/PRP\\$?")
str_replace(unlist(prp), "/PRP\\$?", "")
#[1] "my" "He"
```

Comment: Better to use one regex instead of two `"(\\w+)(?=/PRP)"`