# Selecting text from corresponding tags in a sequence in R

Tags: r, pos-tagger

I am trying to extract text from corresponding tag in a sentence in sequence. Basically I am trying to get part of speech corresponds to each sentence in text file.
      **Code:**

```
   posText<- "The VeriFone is not working, when customers slide card nothing happens. The screen is frozen. We rebooted but it did not help."
   posText1<- c("The VeriFone is not working","scanner is not scanning","printer offline","when customers slide card nothing happens. The screen is frozen. We rebooted but it did not help.")

   tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
   s <- as.String(x)
   word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
   a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
   a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
   a3 <- annotate(s, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
   a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
   POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
   POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
   list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
   }

   dd1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(posText), ' '))
   dd_V1 <- tagPOS(dd1)$POStagged
   dd_V1
```

**Output**

```
   [1] "The/DT VeriFone/NNP is/VBZ not/RB working/VBG ,/, when/WRB customers/NNS slide/NN card/NN nothing/NN happens/VBZ ./. The/DT screen/NN is/VBZ frozen/VBN ./. We/PRP rebooted/VBD but/CC it/PRP did/VBD not/RB help/VB ./."
```

I want to extract text of the tag in a sequence. For example: i want to extract texts whose tag is 'NNP','VBZ','RB','VBG' in sequence from entire text file wherever we have following sequence in the sentences.

My desired outputs is:

```
 [1] VeriFone is not working
```

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: Your example code throws an error and probably needs the code from the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764056/could-not-find-function-tagpos

Comment: Thanks Daniel for mentioning it. I wrongly copy pasted my another code here. My bad. Now i have updated it.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, sorry! Are you sure that this code runs for you? For example `as.String` and `Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()` are not in base R. Maybe you could also edited the question for `posText` being a vector and what the output is, respective your desired output in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather naive approach and in case you have plenty of strings, it is probably too slow, but just give a try

```
# Get the constrol sequence IDs (probably with RegEx nicer to do...)
  tags <- sapply(strsplit(strsplit(dd_V1,"/")[[1]][-1]," "),"[",1)

# Define constants
  matchSeq <- c('NNP','VBZ','RB', 'VBG')
  totalTags <- length(tags)
  searchLength <- length(matchSeq)

# Loop through all subvectors and store starting points of possible matches
  startPoints <- c()
  for(i in 1:(totalTags-searchLength)){
    if(identical(tags[i:(i+searchLength-1)], matchSeq)) startPoints <- c(startPoints,i)
  }

# Print results, if there are any
  if(!is.null(startPoints)) paste(dd1[startPoints:(startPoints+searchLength-1)], collapse=" ")
```

If you find more than even location, you can e.g. loop over the `startPoints` and print then every single sequence separately.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your code works good for me. But if my variable(posText) has below values, it fails to match the sequence. posText<- c("The VeriFone is not working","scanner is not scanning","printer offline","when customers slide card nothing happens. The screen is frozen. We rebooted but it did not help.")

Comment: In case that `posText` is a vector, how does your `dd_V1` object look like? It seems when I use your code, it shuffles already the sentences there, so that the structure in `dd_V1` is twisted!

Comment: Yes @Daniel Fischer you are correct. When i use 'posText' as my input to your code, i am getting my desired output. But if i use 'posText1' as my input to your code, the strcuture of 'dd_V1' gets twisted. It seems string split in 'dd1' is not of equal length. My expected output using 'posText1' is : Extract words whose tag is 'NNP','VBZ','RB','VBG' in sequence from 4 sentences in 'posText1'.

Comment: Depending on the amount of text input you can loop then over the `posText1` object and treat it then as the original problem. But of course that might be slow. Just wrap a `for(j in 1:length(posText1))`   around everything and access then the item via `posText[1]` and handle it as single item. And write out the result in each loop run. Might be slow, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Fischer for your direction. I tried your code with different samples. But it fails if in any sentence given matching sequence is not found. Error is : "Error in startPoints:(startPoints + searchLength - 1) : 
  argument of length 0"

Comment: Could you put a `posText` example where it fails? Maybe the final `if`-clause is wrong and needs some small adjustment.