# Count number of verbs for each speech in data frame R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, tm, opennlp

I have a data frame as the following:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   255 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Group      : Factor w/ 255 levels "AlzGroup1","AlzGroup10",..: 1 112 179 190 201 212 223 234 245 2 ...
$ Gender     : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
$ Description: Factor w/ 255 levels "A boy's on the uh falling off the stool picking up cookies . The girl's reaching up for it . The girl the lady "| __truncated__,..: 63 69 38 134 111 242 196 85 84 233 ...
```

in the Description column I have 255 speeches and I want to add a column to my data frame containing number of verbs in each speech, I know how to get number of verbs but the following code gives me total number of verbs in Description column:

```
> library(NLP);
> library(tm);
> library(openNLP);
NumOfVerbs=sapply(strsplit(as.character(tagPOS(data$Description)),"[[:punct:]]*/VB.?"),function(x) {res = sub("(^.*\\s)(\\w+$)", "\\2", x); res[!grepl("\\s",res)]} )
```

Does anyone know how can I get number of verbs in each speech?

Thanks for any help!

Elahe

Comment: If you can count the verbs then you can also use dplyr::group_by to group by speech and summarise(n()) to count. I think you might get better quality help if you post a reproducible example rather than the structure of your data. Just use `dput(data)` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using function similar to this one (found here: [could not find function tagPOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764056/could-not-find-function-tagpos)):

```
tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
  s <- as.String(x)
  word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
  a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
  a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
  a3 <- annotate(s, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
  a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
  POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
  POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
  list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}
```

Create a function that counts the number of POS tags that contain the letters `'VB'`

```
count_verbs <-function(x) {
  pos_tags <- tagPOS(x)$POStags
  sum(grepl("VB", pos_tags))
  }
```

And use `dplyr` to group by `Group` and summarise using `count_verbs()`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(num_verbs = count_verbs(Description))
```

Comment: I cannot run the very last part of your answer summarise(num_verbs = count_verbs(data$Description)), I get this error: Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: That's because you pass `data$Description` as an argument to `count_verbs()`, if you look at the chain above, you will find I only pass `Description`.

Comment: you're right, then using what you did in the chain brings a new error!Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, do you have any idea how we can use this solution NumOfVerbs=sapply(strsplit(as.character(tagPOS(data$Description)),"[[:punct:]]*/VB.?"),function(x) {res = sub("(^.*\\s)(\\w+$)", "\\2", x); res[!grepl("\\s",res)]} ) to count verbs in each speech?

Comment: You can restart R, and use this `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g" )` (example for 8 GB, you can in/decrease it depending on your machine) to increase the memory that can be used. You can also try to explicitly call a garbage collector `gc()` in `tagPOS()` to free up memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was exactly what I was looking for!